# No 'attendees' listed for recurring events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to list attendees for events on a calendar. I have noticed that there are no attendees listed for recurring events, only the creator. When I look at the calendar through the website, there are attendees listed. I am querying by single events. Do I have to handle these events differently to get the attendees?

```
function listEvents() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var data = sheet.getDataRange();
  sheet.clearContents();


  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 5
  });

  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];

      if (event.start.date) {
        // All-day event.
        var start = parseDate(event.start.date);

      } else {
        var start = parseDate(event.start.dateTime);
        var end = parseDate(event.end.dateTime);
        var duration = (end-start);
        var creator = event.creator.email;

        sheet.appendRow([creator,event.summary, start.toLocaleString(), end.toLocaleString(), duration]);

        if (event.attendees) {
        for (var j = 0; j < event.attendees.length; j++) {

       sheet.appendRow([event.attendees[j].email,event.summary, start.toLocaleString(), end.toLocaleString(), duration]);
        }
        }

        }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No events found.');
  }
}
```

Comment: is the `if (event.attendees)` line failing? Could you try using `if (event.attendess.length != 0)` and try?

Comment: I put that line in to deal with the situation where I encounter a recurring event that had no attendees. I want  to know how to access the attendees for a recurring event.

Comment: the access to attendees is correct, (event.attendees[j]) but your initial check maybe failing, because that's not the way to check it.

Comment: It is not the check that is the issue. If I look at the base return values: Logger.log(event); The return has no attendees for recurring events. I just put the:  if (event.attendees); check in so the iteration of attendees would not fail for recurring events. However, when I look at the web interface for this calendar for that recurring event, there are attendees. I cannot find anything in the documentation as to why the attendees for a recurring event are not returned.

Comment: See [Private event properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#private_event_properties). There is a part there about getting attendees that suggests you should be counting is the responses of the attendees via [`attendees[ ].responseStatus`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#attendees.responseStatus) because it is the only event change that is propagated between attendees and organizers.

Comment: Can you provide us your logs?  Currently looking on the Official Google Documentation for Calendar API – 'Events'. Have you tried using 'Events.attendeesOmitted'? Based on the document, 'attendeesOmitted' can be used to update the participant's response.

Comment: There are no "attendees" properties for any of the recurring events on this calendar.  They are simply not there if Iog the event or if I reference them directly attendees[j].responseStatus is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You may use code snippet below in validating 'attendees' by ID:

```
event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
```

Here's a Official Google Documentation for Creating Recurring Events: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents